# How can i implement an interface like BB Messenger?

Tags: blackberry

How can i implement an interface like BB Messenger showing a tree with a list of complex field items that are shown only if the tree item expands.??

Comment: What platform? Blackberry? So Java with Blackberry SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a ListField for the contents of the collapsible area (you control how each row is painted), and use some other focusable field for the header.  Add both to a VerticalFieldManager.  When you click on the header once, remove the ListField from the Manager.  When you click on it again, add it back.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about tree view. for that you can try this.
[Create a field to display a tree view](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11958/Create_a_field_to_display_a_tree_view_508115_11.jsp)